# Is the getReferenceById() method appropriate when I need an Entity that has only an ID?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need a Subject Entity Object for creating user.
(Certainly, Subject represents the most favored subject chosen by the user.)
From client(FE), I will get a `subjectId`. And I want to make a Subject Entity Object with this `subjectId`. But I don't want to query to DB. And I will make all entities' constructor's access modifier `protected`. So I can't make a Object with only `Id`. In this case, is it appropriate that use `getReferencebyId()` method?

UsersSvc.java - signUp()

```
public void signUp(SignUpDTO signUpDTO) {
        Subject subject = subjectRepo.getReferenceById(signUpDTO.getSubjectId());
        signUpDTO.encodePw(passwordEncoder);
        Users user = Users.createUser(signUpDTO, subject);
        userRepo.save(user);
}
```

Users.java

```java
package ssg.baropass.users;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import ssg.baropass.subject.Subject;
import ssg.baropass.users.dto.SignUpDTO;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String loginId;
    private String pw;
    private String name;
    private String nickname;
    private String phone;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "ad_assent", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    private boolean adAssent;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;

    private Integer infoExpiryYear;
    private LocalDate adAssentModifyDate;
    private LocalDateTime signUpDate;

    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Subject subject;

    public static Users createUser(SignUpDTO dto, Subject subject) {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.loginId = dto.getLoginId();
        user.pw = dto.getEncodedPw();
        user.name = dto.getName();
        user.nickname = dto.getNickname();
        user.phone = dto.getPhone();
        user.infoExpiryYear = dto.getInfoExpiryYear();
        user.adAssent = dto.isAdAssent();
        user.signUpDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        user.adAssentModifyDate = LocalDate.now();
        user.active = true;
        user.role = UserRole.MEMBER;
        user.subject = subject;
        return user;
    }

    public void updatePw(String pw, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        this.pw = encoder.encode(pw);
    }
}
```

SignUpDTO.java

```java
package ssg.baropass.users.dto;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Getter
public class SignUpDTO {
    @NotEmpty(message = "아이디를 입력해주세요.")
    String loginId;
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20, message = "비밀번호는 8자 이상 20자 이하로 입력해주세요.")
    @NotEmpty(message = "비밀번호를 입력해주세요.")
    String pw;
    @NotEmpty(message = "이름을 입력해주세요.")
    String name;
    @NotEmpty(message = "닉네임을 입력해주세요.")
    String nickname;
    @NotEmpty(message = "전화번호를 입력해주세요.")
    String phone;
    @NotNull(message = "개인정보 보관기간을 선택해주세요.")
    Integer infoExpiryYear;
    boolean adAssent;
    String encodedPw;
    @NotNull(message = "관심정보를 선택해주세요 ")
    Long subjectId;
    public void encodePw(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        encodedPw = encoder.encode(pw);
    }
}
```